# Why cell.ImageView?.image is nil if have passed an image? Confused with optionals in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicollectionviewcell

I just can't think of it anymore, please help me understand what is going on here:

So I have an assets of images that I'm trying to see in UICollecionView. 
I have an array of images names and filenames, so inside *collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:* function I did

```
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as ImageCell

    let currentPhoto = photos[indexPath.row]
    let currentImage = UIImage(named: currentPhoto.filename)

    cell.imageC?.image = currentImage

    println("collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:\(indexPath.row)")
    println(currentPhoto.filename)

    println("currentImage \(currentImage!.imageAsset)")
    println("cell.image \(cell.imageC?.image)")
    return cell
```

imageC is defined in

```
class ImageCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var imageC: UIImageView!

}
```

So I see that **currentImage** correctly get an image. Println gave me this:

`currentImage <UIImageAsset: 0x7fead1e55790>`

However, cell.imageC?.image is nil! why? I confused with optionals and didn't actually get the idea of wraping-unwraping variables and constants, but here I did everything exactly the same as in TableView tutorial. Please, give me some clues - I got stuck in mud

Comment: Did you connect the outlet ?

Comment: Sure! If I hadn't did this XCode would have said something about my custom cell class not having a member named "ImageC"

Comment: It won't declaring a outlet and connecting it to storyboard both are different. If you didn't declare it (you can't connect it to storyboard and it will show the above mentioned error). If you declare it but didn't connected to storyboard there will be no error displayed.

Comment: I did both, but the problem was with registering class as I found out earlier, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG I commented out in viewDidLoad()

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

and it worked! I'm not sure why, but as a temporary solution it works fine for me.

Strangely, though that this line of code is a part of default viewDidLoad() method if you would try to create new UIViewCollectionController class

Comment: Same here though i don't get it, we're supposed to register the class

Answer (score 0):

If you use the following, it should work:

```
cell.imageC.image = currentImage
```

In you ImageCell class, you define the image as an `UIImageView!`
That exclamation mark basically says that you do not initialise the variable but that it will contain something before being referenced. It is not an optional.

Optionals in swift exist to make the code safer. It introduces the concept that no constant nor any variable contain `nil` for it will throw you an error when accessed. Instead, if there is a chance the variable has nothing in it, you can tag it as being optional. That optional flag is sort of like a boolean that says if there is something in the variable or not. Once you check to see if the variable is not nil, then unwrapping it, you would get the contents of it.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately app crashes with 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)' XCode highlights this line about imageC.image... and says EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (...) What don't understand is that why we use imageC: UIImageView! with exclamation sign if knew that this property always will have non-nil value?

Comment: That is to not have to unwrap it or check for a nil value every time we call it. As for it not working, are you sure the array of photos is initialized?

Comment: Yes, the problem was with      self.collectionView!.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)